Encoded password does not look like BCrypt Spring Security with OIDC
First things first, I want to tell that the "password" column in my db is 255 characters length, and that I persist it correctly to the db:
I've already ensured that: BCrypt version and strength matches. Tried using the debugger, didn't see anything weird in the local variables, until the "passwordEncoder.matches" method didn't eventually yield "false" and of course googled a lot, but without any success so far..
Nevertheless, I'm still getting this error:
2024-09-07T19:46:13.867+03:00 TRACE 2672624 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (6/13)
2024-09-07T19:46:13.868+03:00 TRACE 2672624 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/2)
2024-09-07T19:46:13.871+03:00  WARN 2672624 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2024-09-07T19:46:13.871+03:00 DEBUG 2672624 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
2024-09-07T19:46:13.871+03:00 TRACE 2672624 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
2024-09-07T19:46:13.873+03:00  WARN 2672624 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
2024-09-07T19:46:13.873+03:00 DEBUG 2672624 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
2024-09-07T19:46:13.873+03:00 TRACE 2672624 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

UserDetailsService:
@Service
public class SecurityUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    final private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public SecurityUserService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new SecurityUserMapper(), username).getFirst();
    }
}


SecurityUserMapper:
public class SecurityUserMapper implements RowMapper<SecurityUser> {

    @Override
    public SecurityUser mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        SecurityUser user = new SecurityUser();
        user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        return user;
    }

}

AuthServerConfig:
@Configuration
public class AuthServerConfig {

    private final RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService = new SecurityUserService(new JdbcTemplate());

    public AuthServerConfig(RsaKeyProperties rsaKeys, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.rsaKeys = rsaKeys;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()); // new line
        http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/login?logout"));
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
            request.dispatcherTypeMatchers(
                    DispatcherType.FORWARD,
                    DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll();
            request.requestMatchers("/oauth2/token").permitAll();
            request.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2A);
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaKeys.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaKeys.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKeys.publicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
    }
}

I'm only learning Spring, so I'll be very thankful for your help
EDITED
I wasn't sure how to show what the request looks like when requesting through the login page, so I implemented Basic authentication with all defaults and tried to authenticate against it:

and what does your request actually look like?

@Toerktumlare I added the request itself
